# GPU Memory management issues when using TensorFlow

Tags: keras, tensorflow

| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage
|    0      6944    C   python3                                      11585MiB |
|    1      6944    C   python3                                      11587MiB |
|    2      6944    C   python3                                      10621MiB |

The `nvidia-smi` memory is not freed after the tensorflow is stopped in the middle.

Tried to using this

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC'
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.90
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Also

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
with tf.Graph().as_default():
```

Tried resetting the GPU
`sudo nvidia-smi --gpu-reset -i 0`

The memory can not be freed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was obtained from [Tensorflow set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES within jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893755/tensorflow-set-cuda-visible-devices-within-jupyter/37901914#37901914) thanks Yaroslav.

Most of the information was obtained from Tensorflow Stackoverflow documentation. I am not allowed to post it. Not sure why.

Insert this at the beginning of your code.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

# Set the environment variables
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"

# Double check that you have the correct devices visible to TF
print("{0}\nThe available CPU/GPU devices on your system\n{0}".format('=' * 100))
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

Different options to start with GPU or CPU. I am using the CPU. Can be changed from the below options
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
# with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
# with tf.Graph().as_default():
```

Use the following lines in the session:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 1}, log_device_placement=False,
                        allow_soft_placement=True)
# allocate only as much GPU memory based on runtime allocations
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
# Session needs to be closed
sess.close()
```

## The below line will fix the issue of resources locked by python

```
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
```

Another helpful article to understand the importance of ['with'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689566/tensorflow-does-keyboard-interrupt-close-the-current-session)
Please do check the official [tf.Session()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) from tensorflow.

## Parameter explanation

```
    To find out which devices your operations and tensors are assigned to, create the session with 
    log_device_placement configuration option set to True.
    
    TensorFlow to automatically choose an existing and supported device to run the operations in case the specified 
    one doesn't exist, you can set allow_soft_placement=True in the configuration option when creating the session.
```